# Bash script works as it should when started from terminal but it doesn't when invoked by .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

First script is called wa.sh Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 2
/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/selfservice --icaroot /opt/Citrix/ICAClient

VDI=`pidof wfica | wc -w`
echo $VDI

while [ $VDI -eq 0 ]

do
        sleep 1
        echo "VDI is not running"
        VDI=`pidof wfica | wc -w`

done
echo "gonig to if.sh"
/opt/Scripts/if.sh&
```

Contents of if.sh - the second script

```
#!/bin/bash

VDI=`pidof wfica | wc -w`
echo $VDI
while [ $VDI -eq 1 ]

do
        sleep 1
        echo "Vdi is currently running"
        VDI=`pidof wfica | wc -w`

done
pkill -u $(whoami)
```

When the first script is invoked by a .bashrc after guest user logs in to ubuntu it doesn't invoke the second script - if.sh
The logic behind this is that when user logs on to guest session, selfservice starts and VDI = 0 User enters correct credentials and starts his session VDI = 1 and that's when we need to start monitoring when VDI becomes 0 again to logoff guest session. 
I have already tried to invoke the second script with source, exec and $() to no avail.

Comment: What is the output from the first script when used in the `.bashrc`? Do you see the output from `echo $VDI`? Do you see output from `echo "gonig to if.sh"`? Add `set -x` to the top of the first script and see what actually runs. The second script too if you want to be sure it isn't running (or to see what it is doing if it does get run).

Comment: When started by .bashrc there is no output or I don't know how to check it. When I login to guest session, open terminal and start the script with bash scriptname it works as expected (second script as well). Echoes everything. Tried already set -x and bash -nx but only from therminal when it works ok.

Comment: Do other things in the `.bashrc` file run correctly? Show the `.bashrc` file?

Comment: There is nothing unusuall in .bashrc apart from a line that starts the first script. There it is: http://pastebin.com/g0bgWNSX

Comment: `.bashrc` is started for non-login, interactive shells. You probably want to put this in `.bash_profile` instead; it's possible that your tests are already seeing an instance of `wfica` started by a previous shell, so that `wa.sh` never gets past its loop.

Comment: I didn't have a ~/.bash_profile. Created one, put /opt/Scripts/wa.sh& as only line - nothing happens when guest user logs in. Did put the same line into ~/.profile and selfservice starts but script behaves the same as when starated from .bashrc. I made sure that wfica is not present when testing. Just to reiterate it works OK when started from terminal on guest account.

Comment: Update. So I wrote a new single script: http://pastebin.com/c7pbzMCe
Added it to startup $HOME/.config/autostart/
And again, works fine in terminal, but without, it doesn't do the last line
'pkill -u $(whoami)'
.desktio file looks like below:

Comment: [Desktop Entry]  
Type=Application  
Exec="</path/to/script>"  
Hidden=false  
NoDisplay=false  
Name=Startup Script

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with permissions on guest account. Re-wrote them scripts into a daemon and all is working fine now.